# How to get a shallow copy with SRC_URI?

Tags: git, yocto, bitbake, yocto-recipe

I have a git repo with different sdk versions in a `.zip` format in a separate commits. That practically means that there is a whole files in git history and when you clone the repo you will get everything because `diff` between binary files are the whole files.

The problem is that after just a few commits, the size of the repo will be very big (1 commit aprox. 500Mb).

I am using Yocto project and `SRC_URI` is cloning the whole repo with history and that is where the things start to go down, since it download a lot of unnecessary data and that is time and storage consuming.

Is there any way to get only one (the last) commit downloaded in fetch task with `SRC_URI` without history (shallow clone)? Or maybe to change do_fetch task somehow?

This is something I want to achieve in Yocto:

```
git clone --depth repo_url
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe this is **entirely** supported, at least according to the [Bitbake manual](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/bitbake/dev/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual-ref-variables.html#term-BB_GIT_SHALLOW):

*Support for shallow clones is not currently implemented as git does not directly support shallow cloning a particular git commit hash (it only supports cloning from a tag or branch reference).*

What is supported seems to be cloning the repo once, and generating a shallow tarball for it (bitbake generates tarballs all the time to avoid re-cloning repos), which should speed things up for you, you just cant avoid the initial full clone.

What you want to try is using [BB_GIT_SHALLOW](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/bitbake/dev/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual-ref-variables.html#term-BB_GIT_SHALLOW) , [BB_GENERATE_SHALLOW_TARBALLS](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/bitbake/dev/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual-ref-variables.html#term-BB_GIT_GENERATE_SHALLOW_TARBALLS) and [BB_GIT_SHALLOW_DEPTH](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/bitbake/dev/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual-ref-variables.html#term-BB_GIT_SHALLOW_DEPTH).

Setting `BB_GENERATE_SHALLOW_TARBALLS` to “1” when `BB_GIT_SHALLOW` is also set to “1” causes bitbake to generate shallow mirror tarballs when fetching git repositories. The number of commits included in the shallow mirror tarballs is controlled by `BB_GIT_SHALLOW_DEPTH`.

Something like the following snippet should do it:

```
BB_GIT_SHALLOW ?= "1"

# Keep only the top commit
BB_GIT_SHALLOW_DEPTH ?= "1"

BB_GENERATE_SHALLOW_TARBALLS ?= "1"
```